# Wordpress page updates not publishing globally

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache, autoflush

I have a client who is frustrated that the updates she does are not appearing online. If the client misses flushing cache, is there a way to do that automatically. Is there any plugin that would not increase the size of the already large site and get this job done. Thanks for your advice

removing cache codes in httacess has not helped

Answer (score 0):

I use WP Rocket for my clients. Its basically one click in the wp-admin to clear cache. If you want to automate it you could try working with CRON jobs ( for resetting cache once a day for example). Here a guide for WP Rocket:

https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/494-how-to-clear-cache-via-cron-job